# Almost only "test orders" in order management in my Google Play Console

Tags: google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have a little problem actually with one of my apps on the Google Play Developer console... Almost all of the in-app purchases (products or subscriptions) are now marked as "Test Order" and have a $0.00 purchase price.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Do you have an idea of what's happening? Should I update anything in my app code?

Comment: can u make a test purchase on real app using your test email address. Capture logs and update them in question.

Comment: did you find out what the issue was? if so, can you update the question?

Answer (score -1):

So I read that you need to push your app into a production state, it is probably still in beta or alpha mode. Can you try that and see what happens?